# Angular firebase filtering data with 3-way binding

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have a simple angular app with a a data array:

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
      {name: "Alice", age: 28},
      {name: "Bob", age: 55},
      ...
    ];
});
```

**index.html**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.search">
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="row in data | filter:data.search">
        <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
         <td>{{ data.age }}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Now, I want to start using the `firebase` service to experience cool 3-way binding. So I do something like this:

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['firebase']);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://<myapp>.firebaseio.com/");
    // assume there is already data in here similar to above
    $scope.data = $firebase(ref);
});
```

Of course now my search filter breaks because `$scope.data` is an Object not an Array. Of course I could transform the data, but that would break the automatic 3-way binding.

So my question is - how should filters be applied to this data whilst maintaining the 3-way relationship?

Comment: So how does `$scope.data` look when it comes from `Firebase` (haven't used it)

Comment: Something like: `{"-JFhWFuhkviwWDb2Ud23":{"food":"Mussels","name":"Roy"},"-JFhWS6PUxI3S-MLfFHm":{"food":"Burgers","name":"Terry"}}`

Comment: Gah, thats ugly. I see 2 options really..a function to transform the data and re-apply it to the scope, or create a custom filter function (which I believe may require an array)

Comment: Yeah - I had a few stabs at the custom filter, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I think transforming might be your best bet, I could post a quick 3 line function that would do the trick

Comment: yeah, but that means the automatic 3-way binding will be lost.

Comment: Hmm...is that `ng-repeat` working correctly yet thru firebase (minus the filter)?

Comment: Actually, maybe I could work around it. What would you suggest for the data transformation?

Comment: Yes, `ng-repeat` works the same. Just the filter is broken.

Comment: Shouldn't that filter be `data.search` for that `input` above?

Comment: Yep - sorry - just a typo. It doesn't affect the code. Edited now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `orderByPriority` filter first which converts the object to an array:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="row in data | orderByPriority | filter:data.search">
```

Alternatively, you can use the filter in your controller to make sure $scope.data is an array to begin with.

Comment: Do the saved items need to be set with a priority? Adding this filter doesn't change anything in my code.

Comment: ! Wasted so much time debugging it. Eventually was going to create new post on SO and this very question was in *related*. It's far from obvious, it should be documented somehow. My test case plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/N4zcF1EBtvw8ktKpr6c7?p=preview

Comment: orderByPriority will work even if there are no associated priorities - in this case they are simply sorted by the key names.

Comment: Yes, `orderByPriority` was the solution. Seems to be a lack of documentation around this, which might discourage adoption of `firebase`, as no-one wants to lose the Angular filters. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Anant's suggestion works. Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rwk1/vqVw7/

Can't post as a comment yet.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="testController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search.searchText"></input>

    <div>
        <ul ng-repeat="person in people | orderByPriority | filter:search.searchText">
            <li>name:{{ person.name }}</li>
            <li>age:{{ person.age }}</li>
        </ul>

        <input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="newPerson.name"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="age" ng-model="newPerson.age"/>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="addPerson()">Add New Person</button>
    </div>
  </div>      
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["firebase"]);

myApp.controller('testController', function ($scope, $firebase) {
    $scope.data = [{
        name: "Alice",
        age: 28
    }, {
        name: "Bob",
        age: 55
    }];

    var peopleRef = new Firebase("https://sqt.firebaseio.com/people");
    // Automatically syncs everywhere in realtime
    $scope.people = $firebase(peopleRef);

    $scope.addPerson = function(){
        $scope.people.$add($scope.newPerson);
        $scope.newPerson = "";
    };
```